# как заполнить список через list?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

     typedef  struct Travelers
    {
        int ticket_code;
        char lastname[20];
        int numberofthings;
        int luggage_weight;
    };
int main()
{

    list<Travelers> lst;

    for (const auto& x : lst)
        cout << "ticket_code = " << x.ticket_code << endl
        << "lastname = " << x.lastname << endl
        << x.numberofthings << endl 
        << x.luggage_weight << endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если просто - как заполнить список - то заполнять структуру и вносить в список...

Comment: а как внести в список?

Comment: у std::list есть функция push_back

Comment: почему ошибку выдает?  lst.push_back(travelers.ticket_code);

Comment: у вас lst содержит внутри Travelers, а Вы ему пытаетесь int всунуть. Если был бы подходящий конструктор, может оно и отработало. Но проще написать lst.push_back(travelers) (если я типы угадал)